# PHP: german date umlauts won't work even with setlocale

Tags: php, date, diacritics, setlocale

I googled quite a bit and tried to find out why my german date won't put out **"03. März 2016"** but instead always prints **"03. M�rz 2016"**

```
<?php 
    $event_date_format = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $event_date[0]);


    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE', 'de_DE.UTF-8');
    echo strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y", $event_date_format->getTimestamp()); // Donnerstag, 03. M�rz 2016

    echo $event_date_format->format('F'); // March
?>
```

[image]

Looks like this:

[image]

Umlauts work correctly and fine for the rest of the page.

I was able to fix it with

```
$fmt = new IntlDateFormatter('de_DE' ,IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 'Europe/Berlin', IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN);
$fmt->setPattern("MMMM");
$event_date_format = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $event_date[0]);
echo $fmt->format($event_date_format);
```

Comment: Do you have `<meta charset="UTF-8">` on the page?

Comment: You also need to specify PHP header to be UTF8: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` (may also need HTML header, `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`).

Comment: yes, I have this in my header file: http://i.imgur.com/V6WGBqz.png

Comment: @matt You need to tell PHP (and not just HTML) to deal with UF8 too, see the above comment.

Comment: Every possible gotcha with UTF-8 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279 (i.e. possible duplicate)

Comment: @Qirel I already tried, but no luck.

Comment: @Matt what is the encoding of the file itself?

Comment: How do I find out what encoding my file has?

Comment: @matt What kind of editor/IDE do you use?